# How DB connections and transactions will be maintained in SpringBatch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I have a use case like,

1. Read bulk records from multiple tables(more than 10000 records)
2. Business logic to validate records
3. Updating validated records to a different table other than where records were retrieved in Same Database.

I would like implement my use case with  spring batch and scheduler to run at 
certain point of time.

I have read about spring batch and understand that there is a `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, and `ItemWriter` as job in chunk to execute activity.
Also I would like to implement it using **multi threading** by defining `taskExecutor(org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor)`.I have decided to go with the below approach

1. Read records from DB with query by calling DAO implemented in other module with spring hibernate transaction manager in `ItemReader`.
2. Process the records each at a time in `ItemProcessor`
3. Update the record to table in `ItemWriter` with commit interval of some number.

I am new to Spring batch processing So I would like to understand if this is a good solution to implement or if is there any better way to implement it. I also have few questions regarding how **DB connections and transactions** will be maintained.

Will there be one connection and transaction for the whole batch job? Or will multiple connections and transaction be opened at certain points of execution?  How this process will be handled?

How to effectively process the above use case with multi-threading to process records with 10, or 20 threads at a time?

Can someone please provide a brief explanation to understand more on this concept or provide any samples to understand more?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds good to me .

I will try to answer your first question.

**Will there be one connection and transaction for the whole batch job? Or will multiple connections and transaction be opened at certain points of execution? How this process will be handled?**

You can have multiple data source and multiple transaction managers , but managing it will be difficult , as you will have to take care of many of the thing that spring batch manager can do on its own .
Since most of the spring batch operations like Restart , stop etc need metadata which is stored in Db by spring batch . If you try to play with it then those operations might not work very well .

I would suggest you to have both spring batch tables and your business specific tables inside the same data source .
That way you need to have only one data source and one transaction manager and you do not have to worry about transaction issues that you might face.